# I want to stop the div in the navbar moving, when scrolling

Tags: css

I want to stop the div in the navbar from moving when scrolling. I used position: fixed property, but still not stopping.[image: image here]

Comment: Can you provide CSS and HTML code?

Comment: did you give top: 50px , left: 0px something ? position fixed not working without defining its at least  one side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.navbar{
   position: fixed;
   top:0px;
}
```

or if you are using bootstrap then use  fixed-top

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```